# dplyr: mutate using rows rather than columns

Tags: r, dplyr

My dataset looks like this

```
year Spp  CO2 plantN_mean  N15_mean plantN_sd    N15_sd plantN_se    N15_se
1 2004   A  amb   17.136667 10.723333 1.2615202 0.7507552 0.7283391 0.4334487
2 2004   A elev   23.310000 13.043333 2.7160081 2.6595175 1.5680880 1.5354731
3 2004  AB  amb   14.410000 10.156667 1.1363538 1.7773670 0.6560742 1.0261633
4 2004  AB elev   19.470000 14.786667 2.9173790 3.7358979 1.6843495 2.1569217
5 2004  AM  amb    9.603333 13.510000 0.5515735 1.7176437 0.3184511 0.9916821
6 2004  AM elev   16.333333  9.743333 2.3622306 1.8825869 1.3638345 1.0869120
```

For `plantN_mean` and `N15_mean`, I would need to calculate the treatment effect ratio, which is `elev/amb`. I can do it for one of the variables using plyr with something like this:

```
effect <- ddply(data, .(year,Spp), function (x){
  plantN_ratio <- x$plantN_mean[x$CO2 == "elev"]/x$plantN_mean[x$CO2 == "amb"]
  data.frame(plantN_ratio)
})
```

What is the dplyr version, and for both `plantN_mean` and `N15_mean`?

I guess the answer could start with something like this:

```
effect <- summary %>% group_by(year,Spp) %>% mutate(
plantN_ratio=plantN_mean[CO2 == "elev"]/plantN_mean[CO2 == "amb"], 
N15_ratio= N15_mean[CO2 == "elev"]/N15_mean[CO2 == "amb"])
```

Comment: It might be better to reshape your data so that you have plantN_mean_amb and plantN_mean_elev. That is how I would be tempted to approach it.

Comment: I think you could filter for both `amb` and `elev` separately and then divide the columns if there is a pair of CO2 for each `year`, `SPP`.  BTW, what is the problem in your code.  It seems fine though I didn't understand `summary`.  I thought it would be `data`

Comment: If you change `mutate` to `summarise` in your attempt, doesn't it match your desired output from `plyr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### tidyr is helpful here.

```
install_packages("tidyr")
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr) # for %>% from [magrittr][http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html]
```

#### reproducible data:

```
df <- structure(list(year = c(2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L
), Spp = c("A", "A", "AB", "AB", "AM", "AM"), CO2 = c("amb", 
"elev", "amb", "elev", "amb", "elev"), plantN_mean = c(17.136667, 
23.31, 14.41, 19.47, 9.603333, 16.333333), N15_mean = c(10.723333, 
13.043333, 10.156667, 14.786667, 13.51, 9.743333)), .Names = c("year", 
"Spp", "CO2", "plantN_mean", "N15_mean"), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0>)
```

`df` looks like:

```
  year Spp  CO2 plantN_mean  N15_mean
1 2004   A  amb   17.136667 10.723333
2 2004   A elev   23.310000 13.043333
3 2004  AB  amb   14.410000 10.156667
4 2004  AB elev   19.470000 14.786667
5 2004  AM  amb    9.603333 13.510000
6 2004  AM elev   16.333333  9.743333
```

#### 1. let's gather all the mean value variables:

```
gdf <- df %>% group_by(year,Spp) %>% gather(mean_id,mean_val,plantN_mean:N15_mean)
```

`gdf` looks like:

```
    year Spp  CO2     mean_id  mean_val
1  2004   A  amb plantN_mean 17.136667
2  2004   A elev plantN_mean 23.310000
3  2004  AB  amb plantN_mean 14.410000
4  2004  AB elev plantN_mean 19.470000
5  2004  AM  amb plantN_mean  9.603333
6  2004  AM elev plantN_mean 16.333333
7  2004   A  amb    N15_mean 10.723333
8  2004   A elev    N15_mean 13.043333
9  2004  AB  amb    N15_mean 10.156667
10 2004  AB elev    N15_mean 14.786667
11 2004  AM  amb    N15_mean 13.510000
12 2004  AM elev    N15_mean  9.743333
```

#### 2. let's spread out the mean values according to the `CO2` variable:

```
sdf <- gdf %>% spread(CO2,mean_val)
```

`sdf` looks like:

```
  year Spp     mean_id       amb      elev
1 2004   A plantN_mean 17.136667 23.310000
2 2004   A    N15_mean 10.723333 13.043333
3 2004  AB plantN_mean 14.410000 19.470000
4 2004  AB    N15_mean 10.156667 14.786667
5 2004  AM plantN_mean  9.603333 16.333333
6 2004  AM    N15_mean 13.510000  9.743333
```

#### 3. Now calculate ratio of `elev` / `amb`:

```
sdf %>% mutate(elev_o_amb = elev / amb)
```

to get:

```
  year Spp     mean_id       amb      elev elev_o_amb
1 2004   A plantN_mean 17.136667 23.310000  1.3602412
2 2004   A    N15_mean 10.723333 13.043333  1.2163506
3 2004  AB plantN_mean 14.410000 19.470000  1.3511450
4 2004  AB    N15_mean 10.156667 14.786667  1.4558582
5 2004  AM plantN_mean  9.603333 16.333333  1.7007984
6 2004  AM    N15_mean 13.510000  9.743333  0.7211942
```

Comment: Could you tell what `%>%` does? Is this operator part of `plyr` package?

Comment: it's from the `magrittr` package and is well documented there as well as in the `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would approach this using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c("plantN_mean", "N15_mean") # select which columns to modify
Myfunc <- function(x) x[2L]/x[1L] # define the function
setDT(df)[order(CO2), lapply(.SD, Myfunc), .SDcols = cols, by = .(year, Spp)]
#    year Spp plantN_mean  N15_mean
# 1: 2004   A    1.360241 1.2163506
# 2: 2004  AB    1.351145 1.4558582
# 3: 2004  AM    1.700798 0.7211942
```

Alternately, you could make this much more efficient using `.SD[2L]/.SD[1L]` (see @Aruns comment) which will perform `/` only once no matter how many columns you want to modify and hence skips the `_each` part (or the `lapply` part)

```
setDT(df)[order(CO2), .SD[2L]/.SD[1L], by=.(year, Spp), .SDcols = cols]
```

---

To explain how it works, we are basically ordering the data by `CO2` so `amb` will be *always* before `elev`, then we simply divide the second instance by the first. `.SD` represents `Sub Data` which means our data set with the columns specified in`.SDcols`

Comment: You can also do: `setDT(df)[order(CO2), .SD[2L]/.SD[1L], by=.(year, Spp), .SDcols=c("plantN_mean", "N15_mean")]`

Comment: Yes right. Sorry, now that I re-read your earlier comment, it is quite clear. Will cleanup